# Jasmine - Spying on a methods

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test a service call `loginUser` inside a `LoginController`.
Now it is fine if `loginUser` is global method.

but i am trying to test it after the login button was click.

**Controller**

```
$scope.login = function () {

        UtilsFactory.showLoader();
        LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password, false).success(function (data) {
            UtilsFactory.hideLoader();

            if ($scope.loginSuccessfull(data)) {
                $location.path('/tab');
            } else {
                UtilsFactory.hideLoader();
                UtilsFactory.popup('Login failed!', data.Message);
            }

        }).error(function (data) {
            UtilsFactory.hideLoader();
            UtilsFactory.popup('Login failed!', 'Login credentials failed!');
        });
    }
```

**Tests**

describe("Unit: Login Controllers", function () {
        var $rootScope, $scope, $controller, LoginService;

```
    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('starter'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _LoginService_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;
        LoginService = _LoginService_;

        $controller('LoginController', {
            '$rootScope': $rootScope,
            '$scope': $scope,
            'LoginService': LoginService
        });

    }));

//Success
    it("should call the login method on the LoginController", function () {
        spyOn($scope, "login");
        $scope.login();
        expect($scope.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });


//Fails
    it("calls the loginUser() function", function () {

        spyOn(LoginService, "loginUser");
        spyOn($scope, "login");
        $scope.login();
        expect(LoginService.loginUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

and the error i am getting is

```
calls the loginUser() function
Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined.
```

I understand why i am getting it, just don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`spyOn` does no return a spy, but replaces a method of your object with a spy. So your `spy` variable gets `undefined`, because again `spyOn` does not return anything, and that's why you get this error. Instead, you should pass a method which is being replaced by a spy to `expect`:

```
// replaces method 'loginUser' in LoginService object
spyOn(LoginService, 'loginUser'); 

// ...

// pass a spy to expect
expect(LoginService.loginUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

- [Jasmine docs for spyOn](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out to me. I made the change in my post. I am still getting the same error though. It has something to-do with the fact that i have to call login() first.

Comment: Why do you create spy on `$scope.login()` and then call this spy? Your original `$scope.login()` never gets called in that case, so does not `LoginService.loginUser`.

Comment: Honestly i think it is just ignorance on my behalf. I am new to unit testing js. So i was just trying to add bits and pieces together.

Comment: Try to remove `spyOn($scope, "login");` or replace it with `spyOn($scope, "login").and.callThrough()` in case you actually need to spy on it. Because regular spy replaces original method.

Comment: @R4nc1d, did it help solving the issue? Do you still have it?

Comment: Not really, i think the way that i was going about it was wrong. Even though the way that i wanted to test it should also work. But what I ended up doing was, just started to test the success function. So i skipped the spies. I know how the data will look, so just mocked it out. and tested the response.

Comment: Up-vote because you were the only one willing to help :-)

Comment: I'm just curious why it does not work, maybe it's related to other stuff in your code or maybe the approach is wrong. But from that code everything seems to be pretty straightforward, not sure what else can cause the issue. If you have a time it would be nice to set up the problem on jsfiddle or plunker.

Comment: yea not a bad idea, ill do that and let you know